# "Reset" a function after inserting content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom

People!

I'm developing a website where I have an "Offers List" (iframe). Inside this list (), I have few products.

If the user clicks on a product, this product goes to a "Wishlist" (other , on the parent window). Okay so far.

But, the user can delete the product selected from the "Wishlist". Okay so far. But the Wishlist is "refreshed" dynamically, (with `.append()` method, from an iframe), so my event `$(".button_to_delete").click()` event doesn't work, because the jQuery runs after the DOM. How I can "restart" the `$(".button_to_delete").click()` event after the product inserted in Wishlist?

My code: http://pastebin.com/uHevR1KL

Thanks! :) And sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#listaPedidos").on('click','.button_to_delete',function(){
     //Do some stuff
});
```